# Função mysql não juntar os iguais

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho esta *query* para MySQL:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS Vezes FROM automovel
GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*)
ORDER BY `data_cadastro` ASC
```

Ela agrupa todos os emails iguais, e mostra quantas vezes eles aparecem. Eu preciso fazer com que ela apenas mostre a quantidade de vezes que eles se repetem, mas sem agrupar as linhas.

Tem como?

https://fiddle.jshell.net/e70kz8fo/

Hoje ela exibe assim:

```
email           Vezes em que aparece
pedro1@teste    1
pedro2@teste    3
```

Preciso deixar assim:

```
email           Vezes em que aparece
pedro2@teste    3
pedro1@teste    1
pedro2@teste    3
pedro2@teste    3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem mais de um jeito.

Um deles, razoavelmente simples, é usar `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  o.email,
  i.vezes
FROM
  automovel o
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS vezes, email FROM automovel GROUP BY email ) i
  ON i.email = o.email
ORDER BY
  data_cadastro
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c849e/1)**.

**Pontos de interesse:**

- Apelidamos a *query* principal de `o` (*outer*) e a *subquery* de `i` (*inner*), só para poder desambiguar e fazer a relação dos campos abertos e suas contagens;
- a *query* principal lista todos os ítens, repetidos ou não, sem fazer a contagem;
- a *subquery* lista somente os ítens agrupados por email, e suas contagens;
- relacionamos os dois lados pelo campo `email`, para que seja mostrada a respectiva contagem em todas as ocorrências.

Poderia ter sido feito diferente, com a *subquery* dentro dos campos do `SELECT`, mas aí teriamos que confiar que o *query planner* iria ser esperto suficiente para não ficar refazendo o cálculo para todas as linhas repetidas, desperdiçando recursos e derrubando a performance. Com o `JOIN`, fazemos cada etapa uma única vez, evitando o problema.

Comment: Tá dando algum erro na linha 7 `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(* AS vezes, email FROM automovel GROUP BY email ) i ON i.email = ' at line 7`

Comment: @PedroHenriqueKuzminskas eu quebrei a linha pra formatar, e atropelei um dos parenteses. Agora ta ok, arrumei. Eu de fato tinha testado antes de postar, mas fiz besteira ao formatar.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueKuzminskas se tiver alguma duvida do funcionamento, avise que eu procuro explicar melhor na resposta, é bom que você entenda bem, para poder adaptar em outras situações.